# wp_trash_post retrashes already trashed comments?

Tags: comments, wp-mail, trash

I have a few mail- and update_user_meta functions that fires when a post, comment or child comment gets thrashed.

So when I trash a comment with trash_comment, a mail get sent to the author: "Hey, your comment got trashed." Cool, it works well.

But... When I trashed the related post... The author of the already thrashed comment gets the exakt same mail once more.

This function removes a point from the authors score list a post where they have commented gets moved to the trash-bin:

```
// Remove 1 point if their comment get moved to the "pre-trash-bin"
function trashed_comments_points_delete( $post_id, $statuses ) {

    if ( is_array( $statuses ) ) {

        foreach ( $statuses as $comment_id => $status ) {

            deleteAPointFromUser( $comment_id );
            authorPOSTCOMMENTnotification( $comment_id );

        }

    }

}
add_action( 'trashed_post_comments', 'trashed_comments_points_delete', 10, 2 );
```

Here's the mail function:

```
// Mail author when their comment is sent to "pre-trash-bin" when question is trashed
function authorPOSTCOMMENTnotification($comment_id) {
  $comment = get_comment($comment_id);
  if ( $comment->comment_parent != 0 ) return; 
$author = get_userdata($comment->user_id);
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "From: Blabla.com <noreply@blabla.com >" . "\r\n";
   $subject = "Your comment got trashed";   
   $message = "Your comment got trashed";

   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

wp_trash_post function:

```
// Delete 1 to the current Point Score
update_user_meta($authorid, 'points', $currentQPointNumber-1); 
 }
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'deletePointFromUser');

// Mail author when their questions is deleted/trashed
function authorNotification($post_id) {
   $post = get_post($post_id);
    // Only if it's a post
    if( $post->post_type != 'post' ) return;
   $author = get_userdata($comment->user_id);
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "From: Blabla.com <noreply@blabla.com >" . "\r\n";
   $subject = "Your post got trashed";  
   $message = "Your post got trashed";

   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);


}
add_action('wp_trash_post', 'authorNotification');
```

So the actions gets called twice, thus the user ends up losing two points instead of one.
Basically, I don't want to send a mail or update the user meta when a comment that has already been trashed, is being trashed again when trashing a post.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see your hooks, but where is the call to `wp_trash_post`?

Comment: I've updated the post with the wp_trash_post-funtion. Am I making any sense here? x)